# speeding up redirection in laravel middleware code

Tags: php, laravel

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class isAdmin
{


    public function __construct(Guard $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }


    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        if (auth()->check() && $user->isAdmin()){
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403, 'You do not have permission to perform this action.');

    }
```

this is in my user.php model

```
protected function roleId(){ 
    return auth()->user()->role_id;
}


public function isAdmin()
{
    if (  $this->roleId() === 4 || $this->roleId() === 6 ) { 
        return true ;
    }
    else {
        return false ; 
    }
}
```

this is in my routes/web.php file

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'isAdmin',
    'prefix' => 'admin'
], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');


});
```

But it's slow as hell, can I improve it's speed, I a definitely redirected but it's slow asf, and I want to improve its speed, maybe some optimization can do. Any tips from you guys..

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
class DashboardController extends Controller { 


    public function index()
    {
        return view('app.admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

edited the code to see what's in the dashboard view

Comment: What's in `DashboardController@index`? If you empty your code inside `DashboardController@index` it's still slow?

Comment: please explain what do you mean by it's slow as hell. how much time does it take to complete the request for each block of your code e.g. (middleware, method of your controller, ...)

Comment: Please **measure** how long each part takes. That should give you some insight. If you still can't figure out the problem, edit the question to more more clear and include the measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are some scopes for improvement in your current code as well.

Your User model seems to have nested functions. e.g. middleware is calling `isAdmin()` and its then calling `roleId()` then that is doing `auth()->user()->role_id` and not `$this->role_id`.

Instead of having middleware, use [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies) may be e.g. `DashboardPolicy`.

Your policy can have the method :

```
public function index(User $user)
{
   return in_array($user->role_id, [4, 6]);
}
```

Then Register it inside `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected $policies = [
.
.
.
Document::class => DocumentPolicy::class,
]
```

and then in your controller you will do

```
public function index(){

    $this->authorize('index', Dashboard::class);
    return view('app.admin.dashboard');

}
```

This will be cleaner.

Now to debug the time issue, you can comment all custom middlewares and just keep it simple returning view. If it is fast then one of  your custom middleware was causing this. If you implement the policy approach, isAdmin middleware can be removed directly.